# OpenGL programs and buffer choice

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Let's suppose i have about 20 different 3d models (for example a car, another car model, a house, etc.).

Some of those models works with 3 kind of shaders (so i have 6 shaders because each has vertex and fragment shader). This mean i have 3 different OpenGL GLSL programs.

What i have done is i create one buffer per 3d model instance. For each buffer, i have created an instance of a GLSL program. I am wondering if it is a good thing because some models are working with the same GLSL programs.

I had to work like this because i have created some C++ classes which encapsulate OpenGL API.

Can you tell me if this is really a good choice?

Comment: Objects live in buffers (likely VBOs) which are bound to VAOs. To draw an object you activate the VAO, "use" the GLSL program and the call the proper `glDraw***` You choose the combinations of these three things.

Comment: What i wanted to tell is that i am switching GLSL program with glUseProgram for each buffer.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with calling `glUseProgram` with the same parameter as in the last call.

Comment: glUseProgram are called randomly in fact. If i have 30 buffers, i will call 30 times glUseProgram

Comment: If pair of shaders you are using to draw 3d model changes you have to call glUseProgram. But this will be bad for performance.  You can maintain list of models those are using same shader .Activate particular shader and render list of models related to it. This way you can reduce state changes.

Comment: Don't optimize until you know you have a problem.